# awk modify up to specific line of a data file

Tags: awk

I have a data file with 2 columns and 500 lines in each column. To access the 5th line of the second column I do this:

```
awk 'FNR == 5 {print $2}'
```

and to modify second column, say multiply by 0.8 , I do this:

```
awk '{print $2*0.8}' inputfile
```

If I want to multiply second column, say from line 1 to line 10, how do I modify the awk command?

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sample.csv:

```
line1,1
line2,4
line3,1
line4,1
line5,5
line6,1
line7,1
line8,1
line9,1
line10,1
line11,1
line12,1
```

Your description is not very clear, based on my understandings:

**1) if multiply a value from line 1- 10:**

```
 awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{if(NR<=10){print $1,$2*0.8 }else{print $0}}' sample.csv
```

output:

```
line1,0.8
line2,3.2
line3,0.8
line4,0.8
line5,4
line6,0.8
line7,0.8
line8,0.8
line9,0.8
line10,0.8
line11,1
line12,1
```

**2) multiply all second columns from line 1 - 10:**

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","; result=1} (NR<=10){result *= $2} END{print result}' sample.csv
```

output:

```
20
```

`-F,` means the file separator is comma
`OFS=","` is output file separator
`if-else` checking conditions

Comment: Thank you! Your answer 1) is what I was looking for.